# Zpool FAULTED and replacing disks

Tags: raid, zfs

So this is probably a noob thing so apologies up front.

I have a raid6 pool of 5 disks, I had another 3 disks so I threw them in and added them, when the pool didn't increase in size I read up on it and by what I understood you actually can not increase the number of disk once it is created. Ok, so I let the disks sit there and now one of them up and died which took the whole pool offline since it has corrupted the data.

I do have a backup of the actual raid I have but it would be nice to just be able to remove the disks I wrongly added and then import the zpool again and all would be fine? Help?

```
sudo zpool import -f -d /dev/disk/by-id/ 
   pool: BigTank
     id: 8888859370501390120
  state: FAULTED
status: One or more devices contains corrupted data.
 action: The pool cannot be imported due to damaged devices or data.
        The pool may be active on another system, but can be imported using
        the '-f' flag.
 config:

    BigTank                              FAULTED  corrupted data
      raidz2-0                           ONLINE
        ata-ST4000DM000-1F2168_Z304VLYW  ONLINE
        ata-ST4000DM000-1F2168_Z304YPPP  ONLINE
        ata-ST4000DM000-1F2168_W3010A40  ONLINE
        ata-ST4000DM000-1F2168_W3010AE1  ONLINE
        ata-ST4000DM000-1F2168_W300ZV1B  ONLINE
      wwn-0x5000c5008bc70a5e             ONLINE
      wwn-0x5000c50086eef044             ONLINE
      sdd                                FAULTED  corrupted data
```

Answer (score 0):

##### Situation now

The most obvious answer I can think of would be to remove the unneeded devices from your pool (you should probably have done this from the beginning already).

To remove those extra devices, you could run this command:

```
sudo zpool remove BigTank wwn-0x5000c5008bc70a5e wwn-0x5000c50086eef044 sdd
```

If this does not resolve the situation, I think there is no other option than to recreate the RaidZ from scratch and restore your backup.

##### In the future

[RaidZ expansion](https://github.com/openzfs/zfs/pull/15022) is a feature that was just recently merged in to the ZFS main tree on Github (on November 8th 2023). According to sources, this feature will be available by default from OpenZFS version 2.3.

When this is released (and only then) could you use this particular feature to grow your RaidZ by one disk at a time, using the command:

```
sudo zpool attach <POOL> raidzP-N <NEW_DEVICE>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yipe!

Be very VERY careful when handling zpools, especially when those zpools contain raidz.

What you did was create the equivalent of raid60, that is, you nixed the redundancy of your raidz2 by striping it across the other disks you added.

That was your redundancy gone -- with one disk not part of the original raidz failing, that data was now irretrievably lost.

There's nothing for it but to restore from backup.

And in the future, be aware that raidz is static; you have exactly the number of vdevs you added at pool creation time.

You cannot modify a raidz definition:

- you can stripe it across more disks (as in this case)
- you can mirror it using one or more vdev(s) of at least equal size.

Either way you sacrifice something; striping makes any redundancy pointless while mirroring requires you to add redundancy that you wouldn't otherwise need.

Upgrading raidz means replacing all the vdevs in the pool with bigger ones.